# I upgraded to MassTransit 5.2.0 and existing code is complaining LoadFrom is now obsolete.

Tags: configuration, endpoint, masstransit

The warning does suggest reading the documentation but the current documentation recommends using LoadFrom when configuring a consumer that requires DI support.  Currently using .net Core Dependency Injection.  Can't find a Consumer method that allows DI.

This continues to work.  Just makes me nervous going forward.

```
cfg.ReceiveEndpoint(host, "adjudication-api", e => 
{
   e.PrefetchCount = 16;

   e.UseMessageRetry(x => x.Interval(2, 100));

   e.LoadFrom(provider);

 });
```

Guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

While the use of `LoadFrom` is still supported, it's discouraged because it actually promotes a very bad practice, putting all of your eggs in one basket. Too often I've come across developers who have dozens of consumers on a single queue, all of them unrelated. It's important to spread consumers across multiple queues to avoid bottlenecks, separate traffic on the broker, and get better visibility into the system.

Instead of using `LoadFrom`, consider the following approach instead:

```
cfg.ReceiveEndpoint(host, "adjudication-api", e => 
{
   e.PrefetchCount = 16;

   e.UseMessageRetry(x => x.Interval(2, 100));

   e.Consumer<AdjudicationConsumer>(provider);
 });
```

Then, if you have another consumer that handles reimbursement, create a separate endpoint for it:

```
cfg.ReceiveEndpoint(host, "reimbursement-api", e => 
{
   e.PrefetchCount = 16;

   e.UseMessageRetry(x => x.Interval(2, 100));

   e.Consumer<ReimbursementConsumer>(provider);
 });
```

Using this approach, consumers are spread out across multiple queues (receive endpoints).

Comment: I disagree that many-consumers-one-queue is a "very bad" practice.  In many cases, it makes sense -- for examples, if (a) my app wants consumers gated by the same concurrency limiter or circuit breaker instance, or (b) my app is simple but wants to discover the consumer(s) via DI.  Deprecation via `ObsoleteAttribute` is IMO a blanket judgment that is too hasty.  It breaks those of us who use warnings-as-errors in our CI environments.

Comment: Well, it's a warning, and you can #pragma it out if you think you're doing the right thing. From a support perspective, I spend way too much time answering questions about why every consumer is on every queue, etc. Particularly as more people are blindly hosting consumers in the same process as their ASP.NET Core web site, without understanding the service lifecycle aspects of doing it.

Comment: Fair enough, and I did `#pragma` it out in the two cases I have it.  Thanks!

Comment: Chris, does this essentially mean that autofac is now a requirement for getting DI support in our consumers? e.Consumer<ReimbursementConsumer>(provider) falls over at runtime for my .net core DI implementation

Comment: No, you can use any container and use the .Consumer() methods to configure receive endpoints. There are plenty examples of using MS DI with MT.

Comment: Case in point, this sample: https://github.com/phatboyg/Sample-DotNetCore-DI/blob/master/src/WebApplication1/Startup.cs

Comment: Great to see it in context thank you. I had assumed that    services.AddMassTransit(x => ) had been obsoleted also

Comment: @ChrisPatterson Is there any article with more detailed explanations of negative sides of having a single queue?